# Does this double integral give 0 or does it diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals, multiple-integral, cauchy-principal-value

I was evaluating a double integral using the following iterated integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2xy}{x^2+1} dy dx$$

This simplifies down to:
$$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \left[\left(\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} \frac{2x}{x^2+1} dx \right) \left(\int_{0}^{1}  y dy \right) \right]$$
This ultimately gives me:
$$\frac{1}{2} \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} [\ln{(\lambda^2 + 1)} - \ln{(\lambda^2 + 1)}]$$
Now this should evaluate to 0.

However, the single-variable integral in terms of $x$ is one of those Cauchy Principal Value integrals, where the integral technically diverges but it is possible to assign a value to it.

Using my method, however, I can't seem to get the result that the integral diverges - the limit only returns 0.

I don't know how mathematically correct this is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does$$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \left[\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{x^2+1} dx \right) \left(\int_{0}^{1}  y dy \right) \right]$$mean? There is no $\lambda$ after $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}$!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Maybe $\int_{-\lambda}^\lambda$ was meant instead of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$?

Comment: The Cauchy principal value is $0$. See case 2) here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes sorry my bad let me edit that.

Comment: The integral on $y$ is "noise" for this problem. You should not show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method fails when you assume

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}$

The problem here is that infinity is not a value (as you know), but something we *approach*. And when we talk about approaching something it is natural to also talk about how *fast* we are approaching. As the limit is infinity, we should arrive at the same answer no matter how slow or how fast we are going. In other words

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-n}^{n}\quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-n}^{2n}$

Should evaluate to the same thing thing. In other words, the limit has to be *independent* of the *speed* we are approaching the limit. The easiest way to fix your equality is to write

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \lim_{\substack{n\to\infty\\m \to \infty}}\int_{-n}^{m}$

If you now evaluate your integral you will see that you obtain different answers deppending on how fast $m$ approaches infinity compared to $n$.

Your approach of assuming that the function approaches infinity at the same speed is often refereed to as the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) or [P.V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) for short. So it is correct to write

$\displaystyle \text{P.V} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}$

**EDIT:** You can also say that your approach fails when you assume

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n + \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (f_n + g_n)$

Which only holds if both $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n$ exists (converges).

Comment: Thank you so much. Really clear explanation. If I had an iterated integral where both integrals went from -infinity to infinity, does that mean I'd need to create four different dummy variables and take four limits as they each approach infinity?

Comment: @VJ123 Yes and no. As you said this is just an *explanation*, what we do in practice is slightly different. As you said creating many dummy variables is tedious. Often we tend to compare the integral to something we know converges or diverges and split the integral into smaller portions. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ converges if $\int_{-\infty}^{0}$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ converges. As both diverges the integral cant converge. Comparison tests are also really useful http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/improper/convdiv/convdiv.html. Or search after Improper integrals convergence tests on google =)

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Sir, I remember you had shared a pdf of Advanced Integration Techniques in the community years ago. Do you have an english translation for the same? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac  x {1+x^{2}}$ is not convergent; you cannot evaluate it as $\frac 1  2 \ln (1+x^{2})|_{-\infty} ^{\infty}$. ($\infty -\infty$ is undefined).

Comment: So where does my method fail?

Comment: The limit you got is $\infty-\infty$ which is undefined. If $\int_{-A}^{A} f(x)dx=0$ for all $A>0$ you cannot let $A \to \infty$ and say $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx=0$ unless you know that the last integral is convergent. With your argument you will get $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx=0$  but the identity function is not integrable on the real line. @VJ123

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm d x$$
to converge, it is *not* sufficient that the value

$$ \lim\limits_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_{-\lambda}^\lambda f(x)\,\mathrm d x  = L$$

exists. The value $L$ is known as the the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), but its existence does not show that the original integral converges.

Rather, for the integral to converge, it should be the case that for *any* sequences $a_n\to \infty$ and $b_n\to\infty$ that the value of

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-a_n}^{b_n} f(x)\,\mathrm dx $$

exists and is the same.

So while it is true in your case when $a_n$ and $b_n$ are equal (i.e. $\lambda$) that the value is zero, this is not true for *all* sequences $a_n,b_n\to\infty$.

For example, let $a_n = n$ and $b_n = 2n$. These sequences both tend to infinity. And the value of 
$$\int_{-a_n}^{b_n}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm d x = \int_{-n}^{2n}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm d x = \log(4n^2+1) - \log(n^2+1) \neq 0.$$

Therefore, the integral does not converge.

Comment: Really great answer. I wish I could pick yours too, but I can only pick one :(

Comment: @VJ123 Don't worry about that, the upvote is sufficient ;). I'm just glad the answer helped!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_{-\lambda}^\lambda f(x)\,dx$$

*is* precisely Cauchy's principal value, which is indeed $0$. So this formula cannot inform you on the ordinary convergence of the integral.

What you might do instead is to evaluate

$$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_{-\lambda}^0 f(x)\,dx+\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_0^\lambda f(x)\,dx$$ and confirm divergence of both integrals.